# Does .ideavimrc work on windows 7?

Tags: ideavim

Usually I use **vim**, but now I want move to **webstorm**. I have found **ideavim** for webstorm, but config file (`~/.ideavimrc`)  doesn't work. I have tried `_ideavimrc` also. I use windows 7 and I think here is the problem.

Inside `.ideavimrc` only one line - `set vb`  ( I don't need bell all the time ).
If I run manually in webstorm - `:set vb`, it works, but I don't want every time run cmds ...

`.ideavimrc PATH: C:\Users\'MyName'\.ideavimrc`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8):

I know it's a late reply,

but I found this question looking for a confirmation that it worked.

- Make sure you don't have extensions hidden
- the (dot) .ideavimrc is required
- you  need to restart the ide in order for it to work

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check Yours .ideavimrc extension.
I had .ideavimrc.txt